# Как получить метаданные из mp3 файлов?

Tags: java, mp3

Я считываю *.mp3 файлы но покуда только по именам, как еще добавить сюда вывод альбома, длительности и путь непосредственно к файлу. Нашёл много инфы и библиотек, но там примеры для одного файла.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "D:\\music";

        File dir = new File("D:\\music");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new HeyFile());


        for (File fileloop : files) {
            System.out.println(fileloop.getName());
        }
    }

    public class HeyFile implements FileFilter {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().endsWith(".mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что вам мешает читать много? добавьте просто еще один цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получение мета-информации о mp3 файле, вы можете использовать apache tika Java API. Можно получить Название, Альбома, Длительности и т.д. (требуется подключить jars tika-parsers-1.4, tika-core-1.4)

**Простая программа**

```
package com.parse.mp3;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class AudioParser {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileLocation = "G:/asas/album/song.mp3";

        try {

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
            ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
            parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
            input.close();

            // List all metadata
            String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

            for (String name : metadataNames) {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
            }

            // Retrieve the necessary info from metadata
            // Names - title, xmpDM:artist etc. - mentioned below may differ based
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
            System.out.println("Artists: " + metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
            System.out.println("Composer : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:composer"));
            System.out.println("Genre : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:genre"));
            System.out.println("Album : " + metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

источник [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746415/3873085)

Comment: А как получить длительность и путь к файлу в таком случае?

Comment: до строчки где: `...  = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));` вы можете пройтись своим кодом, где будите получать объект `File`, получать из него точный путь к файлу, а дальше можете примером выше получить мета-данные

Comment: Ну с путем я разобрался, а что насчет длительности?

Comment: попробуйте `metadata.get("xmpDM:duraion"))`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался и с путем и с длительностью.

Путь: `fileloop.getAbsolutePath()` просто при выводе это добавил
   Что насчет длительности, то нашел в интернетах инфу:во первых нужно создать метод и добавить `toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration"))`

```
public static String toMinutes(String timeInMilis) {
        double milis = Double.valueOf(timeInMilis);
        long second = (long) (milis / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        return hour != 0 ? String.format("%02dh:%02dm:%02ds", hour, minute, second) : String.format("%02dm:%02ds", minute, second);
    }
```